# Признаки прилагательных

Tags: морфология

На сайте [Видеотьютор по русскому языку](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/) дается такой морфологический разбор прилагательного.

И точно, она была хороша: высокая, тоненькая, глаза черные, как у горной серны, так и заглядывали к вам в душу (М. Ю. Лермонтов).

1. Хороша (какова?)— прилагательное, начальная форма — хороший.
2. Постоянные признаки: качественное, краткое; непостоянные признаки: ед. число, жен. род.
3. Она (была какова?) хороша (часть сказуемого).

Обратите внимание: краткость представлена как постоянный признак. По-моему, здесь ошибка. Краткость, по-моему, непостоянный признак.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постоянными признаками прилагательного является его принадлежность к определённому разряду по значению (качественное, относительное или притяжательное) и его склонение. Определение склонения прилагательного в школьной грамматике не принято.

Некоторые качественные прилагательные не имеют степеней сравнения и / или краткой формы. В этом случае полнота / краткость должна быть помещена в постоянные признаки.

Положительная степень сравнения также может быть постоянным признаком (т. е. качественное прилагательное может не изменяться по степеням сравнения, например слово особый), однако в учебниках  степени сравнения прилагательных указываются только в том случае, если прилагательное стоит в сравнительной или превосходной степени, а указания на положительную степень сравнения не производится. У этого подхода есть тот минус, что он не позволяет для прилагательного, стоящего в положительной степени сравнения, указать, является ли эта форма постоянным или непостоянным признаком.

Неизменяемость несклоняемых прилагательных также является их постоянным признаком. Непостоянных признаков у неизменяемых прилагательных нет.

**Непостоянными признаками прилагательного являются число, род (в единственном числе), падеж.**

Для большинства качественных прилагательных непостоянными признаками является также полнота / краткость и степени сравнения.

Необходимо помнить, что признак падежа есть только у полных прилагательных.

Если прилагательное стоит в форме простой сравнительной степени, то оно не охарактеризовано в точки зрения полноты / краткости и не имеет признаков рода, числа и падежа.

При разборе надо иметь в виду, что объектом морфологического описания является слово в его конкретном значении. Разные значения одного слова (его лексико-грамматические варианты) могут обладать разными морфологическими признаками. В прилагательном это различие может проявиться в первую очередь в отношении к признакам полноты / краткости и степеней сравнения.

Так, прилагательное **живой** как антоним к слову **мёртвый** изменяется по полноте / краткости, но не изменяется по степеням сравнения, т. е. имеет постоянный признак положительной степени сравнения, живой же в значении «подвижный», наоборот, не имеет краткой формы, но изменяется по степеням сравнения. Морфологическому разбору подлежит слово в том значении, в котором оно употреблено в тексте.

Приведём образец морфологического разбора прилагательного.

> И точно, она была хороша: высокая, тоненькая, глаза чёрные, как у горной серны, так и заглядывали к вам в душу (М. Ю. Лермонтов).

**хороша —** *прилагательное, начальная форма — хорош (в данном значении);*

**постоянные признаки:** *качественное, краткое;( полная форма будет иметь другое значение- "положительный", а здесь значение "красивый, приятный")*

**непостоянные признаки:** *положительная степень сравнения, ед. число, жен. род;*

**синтаксическая роль:** *часть сказуемого.*

[Морфологические признаки прилагательного](http://litrus.net/book/read/145062?p=34)

Comment: Спасибо, это меняет суть. На том сайте краткость/полнота представлены в непостоянных признаках.  Я правильно поняла, в этом примере краткость непостоянный признак. Мать больная мать больна. больна - непостоянный признак.

Comment: Да, это так.Больна-больная-непостоянный признак.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо,

Comment: *На том сайте краткость/полнота представлены в непостоянных признаках.* - что то запутали Вы меня.  А это тогда о чем? - "краткость представлена как *постоянный* признак"? Я рад, что ответ Людмилы Вас удовлетворил, но со стороны выглядит несколько странно, если пытаешь вникнуть в смысл собственно вопроса.

Comment: Ну да. Об этом говорится в теоретической части. А в примере краткость представлена как постоянный признак. Поэтому и возник вопрос. А в  ссылке Людмилы говорится, что краткость/полнота может быть как постоянным признаком, так и не постоянным.